# printing json values python

Tags: json, python-3.6

This is my json result from the request

```
{
"name": "North America",
"region_tag": "na1",
"hostname": "prod.na1.lol.riotgames.com",
"services": [
    {
        "status": "online",
        "incidents": [
            {
                "active": true,
                "created_at": "2018-03-22T10:53:03.397Z",
                "id": 7636
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I want to print out the value of `status` from `services`

My code

```
    link = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/status/v3/shard-data?api_key={}".format(API_KEY)
    rq_link=rq.get(link).text
    rq_json=json.loads(rq_link)
```

I've tried

```
print(rq_json['services']['status])
```

and I get an error saying `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Is there another way to do it other than using the for loop

`for post in rq_json['services']:
     print(rq_json['status'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you're looking for its

```
rq_json['services'][0]['status']
```

Because, the service part is described in a list, you need to specify an index to get into inner dict

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[print(service['status']) for service in rq_json['services']]
```

More info about list comprehension could be found in [the official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)